# Changing effect / fx of Malsup Cycle based on slide index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cycle

I have a gallery that I am using [malsup's cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) on and I would like to change the effect based on the link that was clicked index (scrollLeft or scrollRight).  I know `.live()` would probably work in this situation but I am not sure how to implement programatically. Below is the code to give an idea of what I would like to do.

```
var animDir = 'scrollLeft';
var animIndex = 0;

  $("#colors").cycle({
    fx : animYarisDir,   
    timeout : 0
  });

  $("#color-controls > li a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this),
    i = $this.parent().index() -2;    
    if (i > animIndex ){
      animDir = "scrollLeft";
    } else {
      animDir = "scrollRight";
    };    
    $("#colors").cycle(i);           
    animIndex = i;
  })
```

Thank you in advance,

JN

Answer (score 1):

Doh! The ticket to my answer was to pass `fx : "scrollHorz"` to the options for cycle and cycle does the work for you.